# How to get record in lightning community's public page with guest user?

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-community, guest-user

I got the following error while executed the @AuraEnabled method from community public page(with LWC) with guest user. I think this error may be occurred because the guest user can't be referenced to the record but I need to retrieve the record with guest user from community public page. I already set up the FLS, Object permission at guest user profile.

[image]

Here's full source code.

```html
//createRecord.html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Record with Field Integrity" icon-name="standard:account">
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input label="Name" value={rec.Name} onchange={handleNameChange}></lightning-input>
                <lightning-input label="Industry" value={rec.Industry} onchange={handleIndChange}></lightning-input>
                <lightning-input type="Phone" label="Phone" value={rec.Phone} onchange={handlePhnChange}></lightning-input><br/>
                <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
//createRecord.js

import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Name__c';
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Industry__c';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Phone__c';
import createAccount from '@salesforce/apex/CreateAcc.createAccount';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class CreateRecord extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @track url;
  PageRef;

  @track name = NAME_FIELD;
  @track industry = INDUSTRY_FIELD;
  @track phone = PHONE_FIELD;
  rec = {
    Name: this.name,
    Industry: this.industry,
    Phone: this.phone
  };

  connectedCallback() {
    this.PageRef = {
      type: 'comm__namedPage',
      attributes: {
        pageName: 'getsessionstoragevalue'
      }
    };
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.PageRef).then((url) => {
      this.url = url;
    });
  }

  handleNameChange(event) {
    this.rec.Name = event.target.value;
    console.log('name1', this.rec.Name);
  }

  handleIndChange(event) {
    this.rec.Industry = event.target.value;
    console.log('Industry', this.rec.Industry);
  }

  handlePhnChange(event) {
    this.rec.Phone = event.target.value;
    console.log('Phone', this.rec.Phone);
  }

  handleClick(evt) {
    console.log(`record value is:${JSON.stringify(this.rec)}`);
    createAccount({ param: JSON.stringify(this.rec) })
      .then((result) => {
        this.message = result;
        console.log('encrypted id is:', this.message);
        this.error = undefined;
        sessionStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify(result));
        if (this.message !== undefined) {
          this.rec.Name = '';
          this.rec.Industry = '';
          this.rec.Phone = '';
          this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
              title: 'Success',
              message: 'Account created',
              variant: 'success'
            })
          );

          evt.preventDefault();
          evt.stopPropagation();
          this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.PageRef, true);
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log('result', this.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.message = undefined;
        this.error = error;
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error creating record',
            message: error.body.message,
            variant: 'error'
          })
        );
        console.log('error', JSON.stringify(this.error));
      });
  }
}
```

```
public without sharing class CreateAcc {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static String createAccount(String param) {
    Map<String, Object> paramMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(
      param
    );

    Application__c app = new Application__c(
      Name__c = paramMap.get('Name').toString(),
      Phone__c = paramMap.get('Phone').toString(),
      Industry__c = paramMap.get('Industry').toString(),
      is_Visible_to_guest_user__c = true
    );
    insert app;

    //  Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('');
    //  Blob data = Blob.valueOf(acc.Id);
    //  Blob encrypted = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);

    //  return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encrypted);
    return app.id;
  }
}
```

```html
//getSesssionStorageValue.html

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Record with Field Integrity" icon-name="standard:account">
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input label="Name" value={rec.Name}></lightning-input>
                <lightning-input label="Industry" value={rec.Industry}></lightning-input>
                <lightning-input type="Phone" label="Phone" value={rec.Phone}></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
//getSesssionStorageValue.html

import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c';
import getAccount from '@salesforce/apex/CreateAcc2.getAccount';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Name__c';
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Industry__c';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Application__c.Phone__c';

export default class GetSesssionStorageValue extends LightningElement {
  @track name = NAME_FIELD;
  @track industry = INDUSTRY_FIELD;
  @track phone = PHONE_FIELD;
  rec = {
    Name: this.name,
    Industry: this.industry,
    Phone: this.phone
  };

  connectedCallback() {
    var jsonstr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('message'));
    console.log(`getSessionStorageValue.js account id is: ${jsonstr}`);

    console.log(`Before settimeout`);
    var now = new Date();
    setTimeout(function () {
      let now = new Date();
      console.log(`Entered settimeout`);
      console.log(
        now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()
      );
      getAccount({ accId: jsonstr })
        .then((result) => {
          if (result) {
            var app = JSON.parse(result);
            (this.rec.Name = app.Name__c),
              (this.rec.Industry = app.Industry__c),
              (this.rec.Phone = app.Phone__c);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        });
    }, 50000);
    console.log(
      now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()
    );

    // this.rec.Name = jsonstr.Name;
    // this.rec.Industry = jsonstr.Industry;
    // this.rec.Phone = jsonstr.Phone;

    // sessionStorage.removeItem('message');

    console.log(jsonstr);
  }
}
```

```
public without sharing class CreateAcc2 {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static String getAccount(String accId) {
    System.debug('get parameter from getsessionstoragevalue:' + accId);

    // Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('');
    // Blob data = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(accId);
    // Blob decrypted = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
    // String accIdStr = '\'' + decrypted.toString() + '\'';
    String accIdStr = '\'' + accId + '\'';

    System.debug('accIdStr is:' + accIdStr);

    List<Application__c> appList = [
      SELECT Name__c, Industry__c, Phone__c
      FROM Application__c
      WHERE Id = :accIdStr
    ];

    if (appList.size() > 0) {
      return System.JSON.serialize(appList[0]);
    }
    return System.JSON.serialize(new Application__c());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the [critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_guest_users.htm) is activated on your org and the class is added to guest user's profile

Comment: Notihng was changed.Already did it. @Raul

Comment: Ah I didn't read this properly, looks like the guest user is not having access to this specific record?

Comment: Yep @Raul. The problem is I can't access to the specific record. I got the record while I tried with system administrator.

Comment: Then you will need to look at your sharing model and reevaluate if the guest user should have access to the record. If yes, then you would need to create a guest sharing rule.

Comment: Already set up sharing rule for guest user and confirmed the customobject__share object   executed with soql in developer console. There are records in customobject__share object but can't retrieve specific records when executed soql from Apex AuraEnabled method. What I'm missing? @manjit5190

Comment: Then it can be that the Id is wrong. I see you are passing accId in the method but using accIdStr in the query. I am hoping that is a copy paste error. Can you confirm if the I'd is correct.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistake of source. I edited my source to full source code of method. I set the accId value to accIdStr variable. Sorry for confusing. @manjit5190

Comment: I can't retrieve the record with full source code of method by guest user.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bind variable so the line `String accIdStr = '\'' + accId + '\'';` is not required. This is used in dynamic query using `Database.query()`. Make sure that you are getting a correct 18 or 15 digit Id like `001XXXXXXXXXXXX` and change your query to use `accId`

```
List<Application__c> appList = [
      SELECT Name__c, Industry__c, Phone__c
      FROM Application__c
      WHERE Id = :accId
    ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I confirmed record Id and query with accId but still can't retrieve the specific record with guest user.

Comment: I retrieved the specific record. Thank you for helping me. @manjit5190

Comment: Sounds great..!